# Can I use FormData API to send an ajax GET request with superagent?

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-data, superagent

I am using [superagent](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) as my ajax library,

can I use the FormData() method to get form data and make an ajax GET?

here is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var request = require('superagent');

var App = React.createClass({

handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    request
        .get('/gg')
        .query(new FormData(e.target))
        .end(function() {
            console.log('gg')
        });
},

render: function() {
    return (
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input name="a" />
        <select name="b">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
    );
}
});

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

but when I click the submit button,
it did send an ajax get, but the data of form is weird:
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are 404'ing.  Is that why the data is weird? Also in react you may need to set state or something in order to see anything in response from the ajax... also, superagent is mostly used for testing if I'm not mistaken...  is there a reason you're using this (are you testing?)

Comment: I am not doing testing, but I just do not want to include jQuery in my project due to I've already using react, so I choose super agent. can you provide so other ajax libs for me? and I still want to know is FormData can be used in ajax GET request?

Comment: Sorry I was confusing super test with superagent, are you setting headers? you may need  .set('Accept', 'application/json')

Comment: I edited my comment just know, (accidently press enter), please see the up-to-date comment above.

Comment: It looks like formDate(x) is getting put in the query. I assume you want the result of that function?  It also doesn't seem to be URL encoded. Under general => see the request URL?  That's most likely your problem.

Comment: the query is not what I expected. I am doing nothing with function results, check my code, I just push new FormData() in .query(), let's be straight-foward, can you show me an code example that using FormData and superagent to do ajax GET?